# Ember data POST returns empty payload

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

### Cannot understand why model isn't updating after POST

Ok, I'm very new to Ember so this is probably a very "noob" question.
I have a model that's populated and then I call save(). This sends the JSON data to my database via the RESTAdapter.

My database saves the record as raw JSON just as it was received by the client except it adds an ID and then returns the same model back.

In Chrome, I can see the request go out and come back successfully, but I keep getting this error message in the console and the newly created model is still "dirty".

```
ember.debug.js:19154 Error: Ember Data Request POST http://localhost:9991/v1/resources/troubleTickets returned a 0
Payload (Empty Content-Type)
    at new Error (native)
    at Error.EmberError (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:29610:21)
    at Error.AdapterError (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:83234:16)
    at Class.handleResponse (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:84513:14)
    at ajaxError (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:85011:25)
    at Class.hash.error (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:84585:23)
    at fire (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:3617:31)
    at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:3747:7)
    at done (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:9556:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:9788:10)
```

Here's what the JSON record looks like that's sent to the server and the returned JSON matches this exactly except for having and "id" attribute added:

```
{  
   "data":{  
      "attributes":{  
         "synopsis":"SYNOPSIS",
         "description":"Ea eaque iusto veritatis nihil nisi incidunt, doloribus quia eum quae recusandae. Ipsum.",
         "severity":null,
         "priority":null,
         "network":null,
         "date-submitted":"2016-10-20T17:31:41.691Z",
         "date-resolved":null,
         "date-verified":null,
         "sme":null,
         "resolution":null,
         "resolution-desc":null,
         "current-status":"New",
         "date-last-contact":null,
         "orig-phone":"+612-75-8202261",
         "orig-address":null,
         "orig-first-name":"Kameko",
         "orig-last-name":"Crane",
         "orig-email":"sihoregew@yahoo.com",
         "sub-first-name":"Noble",
         "sub-last-name":"Booth",
         "sub-phone":"+685-74-6686467",
         "sub-email":"tiran@gmail.com"
      },
      "type":"trouble-tickets"
   }
}
```

What am I missing here?
BTW... I'm using Ember 2.8.0

Comment: I don't think your response is coming back successfully because of this: "Error: Ember Data Request POST http://... returned a 0 Payload (Empty Content-Type)." Try using developer tools to inspect the response.

Comment: The developer tools in Chrome is where I got the error message from. I also tried this same request via Postman to verify the server is actually returning the model after posting and it is. Is it possible it's expecting the "model" to be in a specific format? I figured if I returned the exact same formatted JSON it would accept it.

Comment: The error you posted is from the javascript console. The 'network' tab will let you inspect the response to view what was returned. Based on the error message, I'm guessing you need to set the content-type header, but I think there could be other issues as well. For example, I think the "0 Payload" means that the HTTP status is 0, so you might need to set that, too.

Comment: I've been using an NGINX proxy to avoid dealing with the cross site scripting issue in my local dev environment and I think that was the problem. Thanks for all the suggestions!